# Identify board game with a castle divider, air plungers, soldier-shaped plugs?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember a game my grandparents had, but I have never found it searching on the web.

This game was likely made in the 1970s, it was 2-player.

It had a green board that was injection molded plastic, it had a set of plastic castle towers and a cardboard castle wall as a divider. The top of the main board was a grid of holes, underneath the holes were interconnected by a network ducts.

The pieces were little soldier-shaped plugs that fit in the holes. It also had two colored air plungers.

The game mechanic was a bit of a cross between checkers and Battleship. You moved a piece and were allowed to plunge a hole as turn elements. If you plunged a hole on your side and the adjoined hole on the opponents' side had a piece in it, it would fly out and be removed from play.

Has anyone heard of or played this game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might mean [Battleboard](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/4810/battleboard).  I found it typing "air plungers board game castle" into google image search

According to information on BGG it was from 1972. It is a two player game.

The photos fit your description of being green with a castle.

the description says :-

> Each player has four knight pieces and one king piece. At the
>   beginning of the game they are placed in the row furthest from the
>   dividing wall. Players take turns moving one of their pieces one space
>   (orthogonally). They then get to use their "air catapult" to try to
>   pop out one of their opponent's pieces. This is done by placing their
>   plunger in one of the vacant spaces on their side of the board and
>   then banging it. If their opponent has a piece in that corresponding
>   space, it will pop up into the air. Pieces captured in this way remain
>   out of the game until that player moves his king up to the dividing
>   wall, at which point he can claim a captured knight piece back (but
>   also tips off his opponent that his king is in the front row). The
>   first player to move two pieces into the front row (next to the
>   dividing wall) wins the game.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly it! I must have been blind not to find it the way that you did. Thanks!